# Python How to edit text all row in column of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I read excel file to be a list in python like this

```
print(results)

[['H1', 'H2', 'H3'], 
['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 
['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], 
['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
```

H1,H2,H3 is header of excel file. I want to change data in column 2 to be like this.

```
[['H1', 'H2', 'H3'], 
['a1', 'b1@gmail.com', 'c1'], 
['a2', 'b2@gmail.com', 'c2'], 
['a3', 'b3@gmail.com', 'c3']]
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: do you want change list or file

Comment: I wat to change list. I can export to csv after change list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = [['H1', 'H2', 'H3'], 
['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 
['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], 
['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
for i in range(1, len(res)):
    res[i][1] = res[i][1] + '@gmail.com'
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[['H1', 'H2', 'H3'],
 ['a1', 'b1@gmail.com', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b2@gmail.com', 'c2'],
 ['a3', 'b3@gmail.com', 'c3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use a tabular tool like `pandas`

```py
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

data = [['H1', 'H2', 'H3'], 
['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 
['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], 
['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]

# read data to DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
df.columns = data[0]

# add gmail in H2
df['H2'] = df['H2'].add('@gmail.com')

# print first five rows
print(df.head())

# save it to a csv
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False)
```

The reason I would  use `pandas` and not `for-loop` and `csv` library is speed, simplicity and easiness. Reading, modifying and storing data becomes easy to write and manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the list to `csv file` after modifying the list, Use:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(results):
        if i == 0:
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            writer.writerow(row[:1] + [row[1] + "@gmail.com"] + row[2:])
```

The contents of `csv` file after executing the above code will look like:

```
H1,H2,H3
a1,b1@gmail.com,c1
a2,b2@gmail.com,c2
a3,b3@gmail.com,c3
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply a list you can iterate and change the values in the second column
like this:

```
for l in result:
    l[1] += "@gmail.com"
```